# How to check if an audio stream is playing using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Currently, I'm using

```
page.$eval('audio', audio => audio.play());
```

to press the play button of an audio element. Is there any way to check if the audio stream is playing?

Comment: same question, were you able to figure it out?